# What is the default state of the multitasking gestures option on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, multitasking-gestures

What is the default state of the multitasking gestures option on the iPad out of the box?

Comment: The developer documentation doesn't cover this?

Answer (score 0):

Multitasking gestures are enabled by default.